# How can I test my ajax using PhpUnit in Symfony?

Tags: symfony, phpunit

I am writing script for testing by using of PhpUnit in Symfony Framework. I tried to test my one of my ajax event through the testing script. But I could not. The ajax will work when the span element is clicked.

How i can do this through the testing script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these lines into your test function;

```
$crawler = $client->request('GET', '/test/', array(), array(), array(
    'HTTP_X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest',
));
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried your code.

What I get is,

`Referencing the "core" extension by its name (defined by getName()) is deprecated since 1.26 and will be removed in Twig 2.0. Use the Fully Qualified Extension Class Name instead: 2x
    2x in CalculatorTest::testAdd from Tests\AppBundle\Controller

Using "filename" as the default strategy is deprecated since version 1.27. Use "name" instead: 1x
    1x in CalculatorTest::testAdd from Tests\AppBundle\Controller`